# How to express "In-toeing & Out-toeing" in simple terms to a child?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> When feet turn inward — a tendency referred to as walking "pigeon-toed" — doctors call it in-toeing. When feet point outward, it's called out-toeing. ([from kidshealth.org](https://kidshealth.org/en/parents/gait.html?WT.ac=))

How to express "**In-toeing & Out-toeing**" in simple terms to a child?

Is it OK to say:

> Please do not turn your feet in or out when walking, keep your feet parallel with each other and point them straight forward!

Comment: ***parallel*** isn't exactly an everyday word for most children! Just ***show*** the child what you mean, by angling your own feet in or out.

Comment: "Parallel" isn't exactly accurate either. Feet normally point slightly outwards, but not extremely out-pointing.

Comment: Out toed is sometimes referred to as "Duck Feet"